# Object reference not set to an instance of an object list to a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, webforms, label

Using a file upload c# webform to insert some records into database. Any errors I get I am adding to a list. After all records inserted i use linq to see if the list of errors has anything in it if it does. I write it to another list and then foreach record in this list I write out the error in a label on screen. Get the error in the linq to list that Object not set to an instance of an object.

```
List<Cups> errors = FDloads.Where(c => c.DataErrors.Count > 0).ToList();

        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Errors:";
            foreach (Cups err in errors)
            {
                Label1.Text += "<br/>" +  err.Lion + "," + err.Value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Success.";
        }
```

Errors happens write at linq line when I write the errors count in list FDloads to a new list and if it contains anything do this, if not do this...

Comment: Could the `DataErrors` object within one or more of your records not be instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
List<Cups> errors = FDloads.Where(c => c.DataErrors != null && c.DataErrors.Count > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: I got passed the object reference error but its not actually writing out the errors to the screen.hmm....It does the label text: Errors: but doesn't look like its doing the foreach loop

Comment: @ERead I see you are writting Cups object properties to the screen `foreach (Cups err in errors)` possibly you should put use `DataErrors` property. Another possibility `Label1.Text` is updated sometime later one more time. Anyway it's another isseu. You should try to debug it and see what is happenning.

Comment: yeah i'll try. Cups is a class that holds the datatypes that i'm writing out to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `c` or `c.DataErrors` is null. Try testing for null before dereferencing:

```
List<Cups> errors = FDloads
    .Where(c => c != null && c.DataErrors != null && c.DataErrors.Count > 0)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I know it contains errors because I purposely added some to make sure it handles them.

Comment: @ERead: You misunderstand. The exception you get is completely unrelated to whether ot not it contains errors. You need to add the above check to avoid the null reference exception. Better still is to not have a null in your collection in the first place.