# IEnumerable<dynamic>.ToList() fails with error "object reference not set to an instance of an object " but object not null

Tags: c#, linq

IEnumerable.ToList() fails with error "object reference not set to an instance of an object " **but object is not null**.

This fails with error:
"object reference not set to an instance of an object "

```
 IEnumerable<dynamic> sequence = GetSwimlaneAttribute(...); 
     if(sequence !=null){
      List<dynamic> list = sequence.ToList(); 
     }

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException:
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
> lambda_method(Closure , <>f__AnonymousType6`2 )    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---    at
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
> System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
> System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.DynamicInvoke(Delegate project,
> Object[] args)    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.<>c__DisplayClassb.<ExecuteAnonymousType>b__7(<>f__AnonymousType0`2
> <>h__TransparentIdentifier3)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource
> x)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource
> x)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource
> x)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()   
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__97`1.MoveNext()    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.PagedItemCollection`1.MoveNext()    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: as your exception is wrapped within a `TargetInvocationException`, your problem pretty sure is somewhere within `GetSwimLane`. However it´s impossible for us to know without any code.

Comment: Please see the below link with the same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973740/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-list-to-a-list-using-linq

Comment: @HimBromBeere That really was the problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The exception you get is completely unrelated to whether or not it contains errors. You need to add the above check to avoid the null reference exception. Better still is to not have a null in your collection in the first place.